# The method addFilter(SerializablePredicate) in the type InMemoryDataProvider is not applicable for the arguments (( desc) -> {})

Tags: java, filter, java-8, vaadin, vaadin-grid

I am playing around with Vaadin and now I am trying to add a filter to a `Grid` that gets it data via JPA and a MySQL DB. It should be very simple and I am rigorously following the examples shown [here](https://vaadin.com/components/vaadin-grid/java-examples/filtering). All seems to be going well until I get this eponymous error message.

This is how I have set up the class data communication.

```
    @Autowired
    CoreRepository crp;     
    @Id("descriptionFilter")
    private TextField descriptionFilter;
    List<db> list = crp.findAll();
    ListDataProvider<db> ldp = DataProvider.ofCollection(list);
    grid.setDataProvider(ldp);
```

And the filtering:

```
    /* Filtration */
    descriptionFilter.addValueChangeListener( e->
    {
        Notification.show(e.getValue());

        ldp.addFilter(desc -> 
        {
            StringUtils.containsIgnoreCase(desc.getFileDescription(), descriptionFilter.getValue()); //<< I get the error here
        });
    });     
    descriptionFilter.setValueChangeMode(ValueChangeMode.EAGER);
```

However, I get this error and I do not understand how this is happening

> The method addFilter(SerializablePredicate) in the
>   type InMemoryDataProvider is not applicable for the
>   arguments (( desc) -> {})

What could I be possibly doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It has to be a `SerializablePredicate`, so it must return a boolean:

```
ldp.addFilter(desc -> 
{
    return StringUtils.containsIgnoreCase(desc.getFileDescription(), descriptionFilter.getValue());
})
```

or even simpler:

```
ldp.addFilter(desc -> StringUtils.containsIgnoreCase(desc.getFileDescription(), descriptionFilter.getValue()));
```

Comment: The first solution worked... The second gave the same error back. Thank you!!!

Comment: Did you try the second without curly braces? (`{}`)

Comment: Yes just did and it worked. Why do the curly braces matter here?

Comment: @JoffJoff because curly braces introduce the body of a functional interface method, from which you need to return